# Buddypress: Check value from bp_member_profile_data

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

guys.

I'm developing a medical online community based on BuddyPress and I'd like to know how to check the value from a specific bp_member_profile_data field. If the user put a specific value (this field is a Dropdown with several choices), such as a Physician or a Student, I'll like to display a specific button on the user's profile.

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `bp_get_profile_field_data($arg)`, like this:

```
if (bp_get_profile_field_data(array('field'=>'Who are you?')) == 'Student') {
    //do smth
}
```

Who are you? - is a field name, can be a field id too.